# LaTeX "Variables" - \@varname

Tags: macros, conditionals, documentclass-writing

I'm currently in the process of writing my first document class file (a personalized resume class), and I want to get a better understanding of what exactly I'm doing. So, right now I'm setting up commands that allow for values to be assigned to variables (not sure if that's really the word I should be using), through a structure like this:

```
\newcommand{\institution}[1]{\def\@institution{#1}}
\newcommand{\datesattended}[1]{\def\@datesattended{#1}}
\newcommand{\degree}[1]{\def\@degree{#1}}
```

So, in the .tex file, the user can use the command `\institution{University of Whatever}` to save the string "University of Whatever" to `\@institution`, which is then later called within the class file by another command.

All of this works as I want it to, but now I'm hoping to create some conditional expressions to control the output. Like, I have a command `\education` that when called in the document will format an education section for a resume given the institution name, dates attended, degree info, etc. that the user had already entered. I want to be able to set it up in the class file to check if these `\@variable` variables have been defined, and then format the output differently based on which are defined and which are empty.

Primarily, I think a lot of my problem is that I don't actually understand what the `\@variable` definitions are or the scope of what I can do with them.

A full example of what I'm trying to achieve would be along the lines of (in LaTeX/pseudo):

```
\newcommand{\showeducation}{%
    \@institutionname -- \@degree
    if \@datesattended is defined:
        \newline \@datesattended
    clear \@institutionname, \@datesattended, \@degree
}
```

So, if `\@datesattended` were defined, the formatting would change to accommodate it. Otherwise, the command would just pass over it, printing the information that was given.

Comment: question's a bit vague to answer but note `\def` is just the primitive underlying `\newcommand` so there is no difference in the type of construct defined `\degree` and `\@degree` are both just control sequences referring to macros defined in your document, the `@` is just a letter in this context, it does not denote a "variable". You could use `\newcommand{\degree}[1]{\newcommand\@degree{#1}}` or `\def\degree#1{\def\@degree{#1}}`

Comment: The `\@somename` macros are 'considered' internal commands which are not to be applied by the 'ordinary' LaTeX user (thereby being kernel or somewhat critical commands controlling a lot of internal setups, which may be corrupted by an unexperienced user)

Comment: Your are after `\ifdefined\somecommand   ... \else... \fi` . It's a primitive

Comment: For this sort of thing, you might find a key-value approach offers a lot more flexibility.  Nesting conditions can quickly become a frustrating experience.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing special about `\@variable` commands. They are just macros, for storing content rather than performing other operations.
As such it's possible to test for being defined, by using  `\ifdefined`, a (e-TeX) primitive.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}


\makeatletter

\newcommand{\@institutionname}{Ministry of Silly Walks}
\newcommand{\@degree}{Minster of Silly Walks}

%\newcommand{\@datesattended}{1969}


\newcommand{\showeducation}{%
    \@institutionname\ -- \@degree
    \ifdefined\@datesattended 
        \newline \@datesattended  % Please use some 'better' setup here
        \else
     \let\@institutionname\relax
     \let\@datesattended\relax 
     \let\@degree\relax
     \fi
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\showeducation   % Date should not be printed

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@datesattended}{1969}
\makeatother

\showeducation % Now it should be printed, but the rest is \relax`ed


\end{document}
```

**Edit** The same should be achievable using `\ifdef` from `etoolbox` package

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: @Kevin: You're welcome ;-)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: That's the original code by the OP, not mine.. It's not my intention to introduce whatever improvements, just to show how `\ifdefined` works. But thanks

Comment: @barbarabeeton What improvements were you suggesting? I'm certainly open to constructive criticism regarding whatever things I've inevitably done wrong or poorly.

Comment: @Kevin: She referred to the `--` stuff. See my edited example, where I added a `\` after `\@institutionname` to provide the correct spacing

Answer (score 11):

Maybe better than `\newcommand[1]...` is usage of toks registers:

```
\newtoks\institution  \newtoks\datesattended  \newtoks\degree
```

If user says

```
\institution{Ministry of Silly Walks}
```

then you can use this value in your macros as:

```
\the\institution
```

If you need to test, if the value of the "variable" was already set, you can  do:

```
\if\relax\the\degree\relax The degree isn't set.\else The degree is set.\fi
```