# Custom Exam Class Grading Table: How to Access numinrange for Custom Command

Tags: exam

How do I take the output from `\numqinrange` and use it in my own custom command?

I have created a custom grading table for the Exam Class. This allows me to add custom elements to the table that we use for grading our exam. Everything in my exam latex file is automatic (question totals, number of points per section, etc.), thereby leading to less user-error in making exams in the future. However, currently, in order to use my custom `\GradingTable` command, you must enter the start and end of the ranges of questions. How can I make this automatic? Since `\numqinrange` outputs the exact numbers I need, it would be nice to get this into the `\GradingTable` command.

I have attempted many solutions to this including `\expandafter`, but I am not familiar enough with LaTeX to make it work.

Here is a minimum working example:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt, addpoints]{exam}

% Grading Table Packages
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\section*{Section A}
\label{section-a}
\begingradingrange{seca}
\question[4] Question Text
\question[7] Question Text
\endgradingrange{seca}

\section*{Section B}
\label{section-b}
\begingradingrange{secb}
\question[2] Question Text
\question[8] Question Text
\endgradingrange{secb}

\end{questions}

\newcounter{QNum}
\newcommand{\InnerContent}[2]{
    \forloop{QNum}{#1}{\value{QNum} < \fpeval{#2+1}}
    {   \\\hline
        $\theQNum$ &
        \pointsofquestion{\value{QNum}} &
        \makecell{\vspace{-1mm} \\ ------ \\ \vspace{-1mm}} &
        \makecell{\vspace{-1mm} \\ ------ \\ \vspace{-1mm}}}
}

\newcommand{\GradingTable}[3]{
\adjustbox{valign=t}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{#1} \\\hline
    Q & P & M1 & M2%
    \InnerContent{#2}{#3}
    \\\hline
\end{tabular}
}
}

% These numbers: "1,2,3,4" are hard coded. How can I use the "numinrange" to automate this?
\GradingTable{Section A}{1}{2}
\GradingTable{Section B}{3}{4}

% This does not work
% \GradingTable{Section A}{1}{\numqinrange{seca}}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

Lloyd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote a bit `\InnerContent` so now you can use `\GradingTable{<title of the table>}{<range>}`.

For example, `\GradingTable{Section A}{seca}` will generate the first table, where the question numbers  within the range will be filled in automatically.

The first time it will be compiled three times to build the tables.

[image: a]

(Added a question and the starting question number for testing purposes)

```
\documentclass[12pt, addpoints]{exam}

% Grading Table Packages
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcounter{QNum}
%% ************************************  added
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\InnerContent}[1]{% #1 => range name
\@ifundefined{range@#1@firstq}{\\\hline &&&}{%      
    \forloop{QNum}{\csname range@#1@firstq\endcsname}{\numexpr\value{QNum}-1  <\csname range@#1@lastq\endcsname}
    { \\\hline
        \theQNum &
        \pointsofquestion{\value{QNum}} &
        \makecell{\vspace{-1mm} \\ ------ \\ \vspace{-1mm}} &
        \makecell{\vspace{-1mm} \\ ------ \\ \vspace{-1mm}}
    }}
        }   
\makeatother
%%***********************************************

\newcommand{\GradingTable}[2]{% #1 => table title, #2 => range name
\adjustbox{valign=t}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{#1} \\\hline
        Q & P & M1 & M2%
        \InnerContent{#2}
        \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
                }
                        }

\begin{document}
    
\begin{questions}
    
    \addtocounter{question}{5} % added for testing
    \section*{Section A}
    \label{section-a}
    \begingradingrange{seca}
    \question[4] Question Text 1
    \question[7] Question Text 2
    \endgradingrange{seca}

    
    \section*{Section B}
    \label{section-b}
    \begingradingrange{secb}
    \question[2] Question Text 3
    \question[8] Question Text 4
    \question[10] Question Text 5  % added for testing
    \endgradingrange{secb}      

\end{questions}

\GradingTable{Section A}{seca}

\bigskip

\GradingTable{Section B}{secb}  
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. I am still trying to understand the @references. Are those from the exam class?

Comment: @Lloyd (You wrote 90%!)  Usually a macro with @ in their name is an internal macro command of a class or package. See the comments in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239305/latex-variables-varname